# syntastic - Set jslint arguments

Tags: vim, jslint, syntastic

I like JSLint and I like it strict!

I've been using the fantastic syntastic plugin for vim today, and I love it. But I just noticed that the options given to jslint made it too kind. Is there any way I can set the jslint options from within the `vimrc`, or do I need to fork/modify the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_jslint_args = "--your --options --here"
```

Setting this variable to an empty string `""` is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
        let g:syntastic_javascript_jshint_conf = '$HOME/vimfiles/mycustomfiles/.jshintrc'
```

and have you config in .jshintrc

Comment: This is helpful for JSHint, but how about JSLint ?

Comment: oops, I used to use jslint but moved to jshint. Sorry I misread your question!